# Gap between nav bar and banner, but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

does anybody know why there is a gap between my banner and navbar? This gap appears in Edge and Chrome, but not Firefox.

I've reduced all of the margins, that I can think of, to 0. Doing this removed the gap in Firefox but not the other browsers.

I've used Chrome and Edge's developer tools to inspect the gap and it actually falls under the `.wrapper` class. This is the parent of both the `.navbar` and `.banner`, so I can't figure out what is causing its meaningless existence!

[What it should look like - i.e Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USBYf.png)

[What it looks like in Edge and Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rhPF.png)

HTML:

```
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags menu_tags %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv"X-UA-Compatible" Content = "IE=Edge">
        <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1>

        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

        <title>{% block title %}MyBlog Title{% endblock title %}</title>
        <link href="{% static 'reset.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'myblog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- MyBlog custom styles -->
        <link href="{% static 'myblog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src=https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        {% render_block "css" %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!--<div class="blog-header"></div>-->
            <div class ="banner">
                <h1 id="logo">Patch's Soapbox </h1>
                <!--<img class = "blog-header" src="../../media/images/banner.png">-->
            </div>
            {% cms_toolbar %}
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <!--<a href=""><img src="{% static '#' %}"/></a>-->
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            {% show_menu 0 1 0 100 "menu.html" %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="container-full">
                {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
            </div>

            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>  
        <footer class="footer">
         <div class="container-full">
          <p class="text-muted">{% block footer %}Patch The Bill&copy; 2015{%endblock footer%}</p>
         </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bu -->
        <script src="{% static "ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js" %}"></script>

        {% render_block "js" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    position : relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    /*margin-bottom: 60px;*/
    font-family : Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #555;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-bottom:-60px;
}
h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3, h4, .h4, h5, .h5, h6, .h6 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serfi;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333;
}
.footer,.push {
    height:50px;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    clear:both;
    padding-bottom:0;
    padding-left : 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 60px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
footer.footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
.blog-header {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    /*border-bottom: solid #C6C6C6*/
}
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.blog-title {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.blog-description{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #999;
}
.sidebar-module{
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 -15px 15px;
}
.sidebar-module-inset {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.sidebar-module-inset p:last-child,
.sidebar-module-inset ul:last-child,
.sidebar-module-inset ol:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.pager {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    text-align: left;
}
.pager > li > a {
    width: 140px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.blog-post{
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.blog-post-title{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.blog-post-meta {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color : #999;
}
body > container {
    padding: 0px 0px 0;
}
.container .text-muted {
    margin: 0 0;
}
.footer > .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 0;
    bottom:0;
}
.row {
    margin-right: 0px!important;
}
.navbar { margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top:0
}
.footer { margin-bottom: 0;}
.banner {background-color: green;
        min-height: 120px;
        padding-bottom:0
}
#logo {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -50px;
    text-align:right;
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to debug if we had a live example that we could inspect :/ The provided HTML is not even compiled

Comment: Fair comment. I'm new to this. Do you have any suggestions on how I could do that? It's not currently on the line

Comment: You could either copy the real HTML output or give us a link to your live page on a server somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Use -webkit-padding-before for top padding, -webkit-padding-after for bottom padding.

(Top) - -webkit-padding-before

(Right - -webkit-padding-end

(Bottom) - -webkit-padding-after

(Left) - -webkit-padding-start

see document on browser specific hacks

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

or maybe could try this media query:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
/* rules only apply in saf3+, chrome1+ */
}
```